# onClick method passed down as prop isn't executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

State is set with useState in App.js header component:

```
const [showAddTask, setShowAddTask] = useState(false);
```

Returned by App.js:

```
  <div>
    <Header onAdd={() => setShowAddTask(!showAddTask)} />
    {showAddTask && <AddTask />}
  </div>
```

Header component:

```
const Header = ({ onAdd }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Button onClick={onAdd} />
    </header>
  );
};
```

When the button in the Header component is clicked, I expect the associated form (returned by the AddTask component) to show because its value should be set to true (the opposite of its default value) and this should cause it to render thanks to the short-circuit conditional `{showAddTask && <AddTask />}` but nothing happens.

If I set the default value for `showAddTask` to true, the form does show.

What could be the cause? In Chrome developer tools, I only get "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."

[Repo with full code](https://github.com/nataliecardot/react-task-tracker/tree/dca2b6312d724ab46ca8c50029cb116409fc27ba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked for your repo, the problem is - you are using custom `<Button>` component, that doesn't handle onClick event.

https://github.com/nataliecardot/react-task-tracker/blob/master/src/components/Button.js -
line 7

Adding `onClick` handler to the `<button>` element should help

```
const Button = ({ color, text, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button style={{ backgroundColor: color }} className="btn" onClick={onClick}>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
```